# How to convert string to date time in specific format and assign it to date property in c#

Tags: c#, date

I am converting "dd/MM/yyyy" format to "yyyy-MM-dd" using .ToString() but how to assign this string result in date property as I am using QBO API where i need to pass the transaction date variable only in "yyyy-MM-dd" as it will not accept the string variable. If i convert the string result in datetime then again the result is getting changed in "dd/MM/yyyy".

how to achieve that my system datetime time format is English UK.

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have any implicit format. You can parse your `string` to `DateTime` and you can use `.ToString(string)` method for representation of it. But since you try assign this value to a `.Date` property, you just need to parse your string. There is nothing as _.Date property always accept "yyyy-MM-dd format"_. It is a string representation of it, that's why it is a `string`.

Comment: You can do somthing like this : 

    string myFormattedDate = DateTime.Parse("15/06/2014").Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

// result : 2014-06-15

Comment: .ToString() can change the format but it is in string format. how do i assign the .Tostring() result  "yyyy-MM-dd" to date property as it only accepts the datetime variable in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. if i assign .Tostring() result in date variable again it is going to change in "dd/MM/yyyy" format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it :

```
String initial = "12/06/2014" ; 
String newFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(initial, "dd/MM/YYYY").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 

// newFormat contains now 2014-06-12
```

**EDIT :**

> ToString() can change the format but it is in string format. how do i
>   assign the .Tostring() result "yyyy-MM-dd" to date property as it only
>   accepts the datetime variable in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. if i assign
>   .Tostring() result in date variable again it is going to change in
>   "dd/MM/yyyy" format

If you want to assign back the newFormat to a DateTime you must parse it.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(newFormat , "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: ToString() can change the format but it is in string format. how do i assign the .Tostring() result "yyyy-MM-dd" to date property as it only accepts the datetime variable in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. if i assign .Tostring() result in date variable again it is going to change in "dd/MM/yyyy" format

Comment: I made an update to your post

Comment: getting error No overload for method 'ParseExact' takes 2 arguments

Answer (score 1):

You could try to parse at first the string:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

where `input` is the string with your date, `12/06/2014`.

Then you could get the string you want as below:

```
string output = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

DateTime newDt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For more information about `DateTime.ParseExact` please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: ToString() can change the format but it is in string format. how do i assign the .Tostring() result "yyyy-MM-dd" to date property as it only accepts the datetime variable in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. if i assign .Tostring() result in date variable again it is going to change in "dd/MM/yyyy" format

Answer (score 0):

First create a `DateTime` object from your string

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("12/06/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then from that object you can achieve anything you want like this

```
dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

OR

```
MyDateTimePicker.SelectedDate = dt;
```

**EDIT:** According to your requirement do this

```
MyDateTimePicker.SelectedDate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: ToString() can change the format but it is in string format. how do i assign the .Tostring() result "yyyy-MM-dd" to date property as it only accepts the datetime variable in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. if i assign .Tostring() result in date variable again it is going to change in "dd/MM/yyyy" format

Comment: @himvj: Read my edited answer.

Comment: @himvj: Hope my answer gets accepted.

Answer (score -1):

By default, your `DateTime` value will always be returned as the system local. You'll need to use `.ToString(string format)` on the `DateTime` object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The above link should give you all the information you need on the formatting.

Comment: ToString() can change the format but it is in string format. how do i assign the .Tostring() result "yyyy-MM-dd" to date property as it only accepts the datetime variable in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. if i assign .Tostring() result in date variable again it is going to change in "dd/MM/yyyy" format

Answer (score -1):

I suggest keeping the date format however your pc (region) has it, and only manipulating it when you "show" it on screen.

You can format it when displaying it, like this:

```
.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Someone care to comment on the down vote?

Comment: ToString() can change the format but it is in string format. how do i assign the .Tostring() result "yyyy-MM-dd" to date property as it only accepts the datetime variable in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. if i assign .Tostring() result in date variable again it is going to change in "dd/MM/yyyy" format

Comment: You don't re-assign it... you always "keep" it in date format, not string format... Only when you "display" it, do you format it to whatever string format you like. If you need to "keep" it somewhere on screen, and read it, keep it as a date variable in a .tag property if you must.